# Luhn checksum method; separating two digits and finding the sum of that list

Tags: python, list, luhn

I am currently trying to use the luhn method to determine whether a credit card is valid or not in python and here is what I have so far:

```
print('What is your Credit Card number? :) (please put a space between each number)')
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

lengthy = len(a)
print(lengthy)
a.reverse()
print(a)

listx2 = []
listx1 = []
for x in range(len(a)):
    modulus = x % 2
    print(x, a[x])
    if modulus != 0:
        listx2.append(a[x]*2)
    else:
        listx1.append(a[x])
print(listx2)
print(listx1)
```

I don't know how to do the next step which is getting the sum of all of the digits of the numbers multiplied by two.(listx2) I have looked at different programs with the luhn method but I just can't seem to pick that part out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation of the Luhn algo.

```
def luhn(sequence):
digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(sequence)] # converts a full string of nums to a list comp of individual numbers
odd = digits[-1::-2] # string stepping (-1) indicates last item in list (-2) means to travel back another 2
even = digits[-2::-2]
checksum = 0
checksum += sum(odd)
evenmod = []
for digit in even:
    if digit * 2 > 9:
        digit = digit * 2
        digit = int(str(digit)[0]) + int(str(digit)[1])
    else:digit = digit * 2
    evenmod.append(digit)
checksum += sum(evenmod)
if checksum % 10 == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False


print luhn(378282246310005)
print luhn(111111111111111)
print luhn(4751290083628479)
print luhn(5573485043994670)
```

Separate the even and the odd indeces to separate lists, then use a `for` statement to loop through the list, multiplying the list entries by two.

Notice the if statement that catches the issue with (e.g) 8 * 2 = 16.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum`:

```
summed_x2 = sum(listx2)
```